# QGIS3 symbology rule-based: use expression in string field for symbol

Tags: qgis-3, symbology

I have a shapefile that contains a string field and in there is an expression called 'Grabeland'. This expression is part of longer expressions but I only want to use the expression 'Grabeland' for the symbol. I started with the following expression`"Kol_Tl_Nam" is '%Grabeland%'`. So far, I can't see the symbology in the map canvas.[image]

Answer (score 4):

The operator `is` is basically the same as `=`, so in your example your are comparing the field with the value `%Grabeland%` (including the %)

You need to use the `like` operator, which can replace the `%` by "any character"

`"Kol_Tl_Nam" LIKE '%Grabeland%'`

Answer (score 3):

Though technically correct, your expression doesn't return a value using which your rule could be enforced. You need to get a `yes/no` "answer" from your rule. So either expand your expression to `if("Kol_Tl_Nam" IS '%Grabeland%',1,0)` - or turn to the built in check `regexp_match`.

The correct expression would be

`regexp_match("Kol_Tl_Nam",'Grabeland')`

If your field contains the string you hand to `regexp_match()`, you get an integer value larger than 0, hence indicating to your rule "yeah, we found the fugitive". Otherwise a `0` is returned.

Comment: `is` returns a boolean and is perfectly valid for rule definitions.